# How to detect outliers in time series data of multiple individuals?

Tags: python, r, time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have time series data of a thousand people.

I want to make a model that finds outliers in the time series of the remaining 200 people by training about 800 outlier labeled data.

The data consists of a total of 4 columns.

x1: id (User Classification)

x2: datetime

x3: value

x4: outlier label

Each user has a different time series interval.

for example)

Person 1: 2020.01.01 ~ 2020.11.31 (11 rows)

Person 2: 2020.03.14 ~ 2020.08.11 (130 rows)

Person 3: 2020.02.22 ~ 2020.07.29 (88 rows)...

x4(label) is a 0,1 value indicating whether each x3(value) is an outlier at each time point.

I'm at a loss as to how to train this data.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to train this type of time series data as a model.

P.S. If possible, I would appreciate it if you could provide a python or R code example.

Comment: This is not a programming question - and would be better asked on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you want to use the labeled data for training, then this is a supervised classification problem. Outlier/anomaly detection is almost always using unsupervised learning.

Comment: If you have labels for each time-point, and want also to get that out, then you should first try to treat the problem as individual instances, and see how far that gets you.